# date processes first parameter incorrectly if it is not 1

Tags: bash, date

I am using `date (GNU coreutils) 8.22` and having some trouble to calculate a date after a given one.

Say I want to use 1st of February, for example:

```
$ date -d'1 February'
Sun Feb  1 00:00:00 CET 2015
```

Then I want to add a week to the date. So far, so good:

```
$ date -d '1 February + 1 week'
Thu Feb  8 00:00:00 LMT 0001
```

But if I add something as the first item *not being 1*, it fails and returns something incorrect:

```
$ date -d '1 February + 2 weeks'  # returns as if it was +1 week
Fri Feb  8 00:00:00 LMT 0002      # but Fri instead of Thu, also LMT 0002
```

However, if we add more parameters in the front, it works:

```
$ date -d '1 February + 0 minutes + 2 week' # works since we added 0/1 unit before
Tue Feb 15 00:01:00 LMT 0000
$ date -d '1 February + 1 minute + 1 day + 1 week' # works fine
Fri Feb  9 00:01:00 LMT 0001
$ date -d '1 February + 1 minute + 25 day + 7 week'  # works since 1st parameter is 1!
Mon Apr 16 00:01:00 LMT 0001
```

Note this not happen if we provide relative dates:

```
$ date -d 'today + 1 week'
Wed Jul  1 12:20:03 CEST 2015
$ date -d 'today + 2 week'    # works fine
Wed Jul  8 12:20:12 CEST 2015
```

So, why is `date` considering the first parameter always as 1 and some weird action if the date is given with a specific date?

Comment: It doesn't return the same value as one, if you look closely it has changed `thu` to `fri`, and `LMT` to `0002`

Comment: Uhms, true. Will edit to reflect the main point: it does not work as intended.

Comment: It would appear that it is changing the year, try `date -d '1 February + 1 weeks' +"%m-%d-%y"` vs `date -d '1 February + 2 weeks' +"%m-%d-%y"`

Comment: Guessing it is getting confused somehow, as if you specify the year with the date then it works as intended `date -d '1 February 0001 + 2 weeks'`. Also if you just put `1 February + 2` it increments the year by 1. And if you put `'1 February + 2 + 2 weeks'` it works correctly. So i guess it sees, `1 February + 2(years) (1)weeks`.  Because even in your working example it has still incremented the year by one.

Comment: I'm not sure why it even works with `1 February`... try it with the right date format e.g. `Feb 1` or `February 1`: `date -d 'Feb 1 +2 week'` or `date -d 'February 5 +3 week'`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so i did some research and it is interpretting the first number as the year, it would appear that the `+` and entirely superficial and completely ignored.

Using your examples.

```
$ date -d'1 February'
Sun Feb  1 00:00:00 CET 2015
```

Works entirely as expected as no year is supplied.

```
$ date -d '1 February + 1 week'
Thu Feb  8 00:00:00 LMT 0001
```

Almost looks right but you will notice that the year has changed to `0001` as the `+` is ignored and so the the command is seen as

```
 {1 February 1} {+ 1}{week}
      date
```

The {+1} appears to be default for any period of time after the date.

---

Another one of your example that appears to work but doesn't

```
$ date -d '1 February + 1 minute + 25 day + 7 week'  # works since 1st parameter is 1!
Mon Apr 16 00:01:00 LMT 0001
```

As you can see the year has been incremented to 0001. The minutes have been referenced so increment by the default 1, and then all further commands are not part of the date so are incremented accordingly.

---

As further proof of it working this way take this example that does work

```
$date -d '1 February 4 5 weeks'
Sun Mar  7 00:00:00 LMT 0004
```

and works the same as

```
$date -d '1 February + 4 + 5 weeks'
Sun Mar  7 00:00:00 LMT 0004
```

Meaning the +'s are ignored and the first number after them is seen as the year if the year is not previously specified.

Obviously if you want to subtract that must be explictly stated, although is still ignored if the year has not been specified for the first number.

```
$date -d '1 February -4 weeks'
Sun Feb  8 00:00:00 LMT 0004
                         ^
                         Year incremented by 4.
```

Although if you use it in a format specified in the man page i.e

```
$date -d ' Feb 2 -4 weeks'
Mon Jan  5 00:00:00 GMT 2015
```

Then it will work entirely as intended without any year required :)

Comment: To [your edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/211802/revisions), so it was also my fault because I was providing the date in a non-standard way. Thanks again!

Comment: @fedorqui Thats what happens when they make date so flexible with input :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be interpreting the 2nd digit as the year 
and then assuming 1 week(s), so always add a year, as `this year` then I think you will get what you desire. eg.

```
christian@fujiu1404:~$ date -u -d'1 feb this year -2 weeks'
Sun Jan 18 00:00:00 UTC 2015
christian@fujiu1404:~$ date -u -d'1 feb this year +2 weeks'
Sun Feb 15 00:00:00 UTC 2015
christian@fujiu1404:~$ date -u -d'1 feb this year +3 weeks'
Sun Feb 22 00:00:00 UTC 2015
```

Comment: The number after LMT/UTC/GMT is the year...

Comment: Yes Year not minute offset, I'll update.

Comment: Very nice research also, thanks a lot for it!